# Манипуляции с вложенными схемами mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Доброе время суток, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли находить и изменять вложенную схему в массиве mongoose по значению ее полей.. вроде следующего:

```
var mongoResultDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    result:{type:Number,min:0,max:5}, // далее надо найти все со значением 3
    indexComand:{type:Number} // и добавить новое значение
});
mongoose.model('resultDataModel',mongoDataSchema,'resultData');


var mongoResultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
            results:{type:Array(mongoResultDataSchema)}, // ???  
            comments:{type:Array(String)}, 
            data:{type:Date,default: new Date()}
});



mongoose.model('mongoResModel',mongoResultSchema,'results');
```

Если не сложно можно пример нахождения и изменения... или ссылку, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Заглянул в документацию mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html
К примеру у нас есть вложенный объект:

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  //Массив вложенных схем
  children: [childSchema],
  // Вложенные схемы в схемы сработают только в mongoose >= 4.2.0
  child: childSchema
});
```

Найти по `_id` объекта схемы вложенной в массив:
`var doc = parent.children.id(_id);`

Добавить:

`parent.children.push({ name: 'Liesl' });`
  а можно просто создать без добавления методом `create()` из `MongooseArrays`.
     `var newdoc = parent.children.create({ name: 'Aaron' });`

Удалить по `_id` вложенного в массив объекта:

```
parent.children.id(_id).remove();
```

Для сохранения результата изменения вложенных схем достаточно вызвать у родителя `save()`
например

```
parent.save(function (err) {
  console.log(err.message)  
});
```